Did the bulk 2.0 query change how it batches over the weekend and how do I fix it?
We have been doing a bulk v2 query for a long time now and suddenly saturday morning (May 25, 2024) it began behaving differently. Prior to saturday each query would create 2 total batches, one with 0 records and one with all the queries records. Saturday morning this changed and it started batching the query into exactly 6 batches, one with 0 records and 5 with approximately the same number of records. It now is doing exactly 6 batches no matter how many records are in the query.
Here is one of the two queries.  They are both very similar in that they are basic queries and are both under 200,000 total records returned.
{
"operation" : "query",
"query" : "SELECT Id, Account__c, Subscription_Number__c FROM Subscription__c WHERE Customer_Product_Type__c includes ('IXL', 'Education.com', 'Rosetta Stone')",
"contentType" : "CSV",
"columnDelimiter" : "COMMA",
"lineEnding" : "CRLF"
}
Does anyone know anything about this or have had the same things happen where your 2.0 query suddenly started batching where it didn't before with the same number of records?
This change is breaking integrations that work with our records because they aren't set up for receiving multiple files so our query is only receiving approximately 1/5th of the records and then the integration that is supposed to look for existing subscriptions thinks that subscriptions haven't been created that have been so tries to create the wrong ones and thinks that accounts don't exist that do so doesn't even try for other subscriptions.
I can't find any documentation regarding how the "automatic batch management" actually decides to batch records. And I tried using the SForce Locator but it isn't there.  The file that it returns only includes the field names, no locator value so I can't tell the integration to look for the next part of the query either.  I've tried this in multiple orgs now with the same results.  They all are now batching small amounts of records into 6 batches with no locator in the return file.  To get our results we are using the convention shown in the Salesforce developer documentation for retrieving query results - https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/vXX.X/jobs/query/750R0000000zxr8IAA/results
Is there any way for us to fix this so it will behave the way it was before?  Is there something the documentation doesn't say regarding how to get the locator value to show up in the response file?

Hi and welcome to SFSE. To help us help you, please [edit] your question to add detail about how your integration works and why the batching is actually causing issues.

Just got your message and have updated to show our query, how we are retrieving results and why the batching of the records without a locator value makes the results unusable.

Sounds like you need to refactor your integrations not to rely on immediately processing chunks of new data, or ensure these integrations understand they may get partial updates. Sorry, I can't help more than be that obvious; you should never rely on getting all data in one go. You could hit heap, request or CPU limits. Or be tripped up by this sort of change...

I understand that I need to refactor it to not rely on the chunks but as I said in the above, I don't see the sforce locator thing that is supposed to be in the results somewhere to tell the other system to get more results.  We only seem to be receiving the body of the results and not the headers.  Using postman I just figured out how to see the headers in a separate tab but our developers are using a different program and I'm not sure how to tell them to find it when all they are using is the {{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/query/{{_jobId}}/results url.
